# Struggling to understand how this particular code works.

Tags: php, smarty

I am faced with a piece of code that does not make a lot of sense to me. I am working on a website using PHP and Smarty template, but there is one line of code regarding arrays that i do not understand how it works.

```
$SLang =  &SLanguage::getInstance();
    $q="SELECT * FROM texte where text_lang='{$SLang->lang}' ORDER BY text_id";
    $texte = _sqlFetchQuery($q);        
    foreach($texte as $text)
    {
        $texteList[$text['text_alias']]['text'] = $text['text_text'];
        if($text["text_category"]==3){
            $philosophyList[] = $text["text_text"];
            $philosophyListSeo[] = $text["text_alias"];
        }
    }
```

The output of "var_dump" on $philosophyList gets out only the "text_text" column from the database, and i do now understand the structure of how it gets there. Can someone care to explain? How does this particular line of code works? `$texteList[$text['text_alias']]['text'] = $text['text_text'];`

Comment: $texteList is a multidimensional "associative" array. But its assignment has no effect on what gets assigned to $philosphyList.
I wouldn't expect a dump of $philosophyList to be be literally "text_text", but the content of $text for the "key" "text_text".
Also, I would not rely on SELECT *. If you only need fields text_text, text_alias and text_id, SELECT them explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a jagged array.

It's shorthand for this:

```
$texteList[$text['text_alias']] = array('text'=>$text['text_text']);
```

So it's creating a named array using whatever text is $text['text_alias'] brings out, and assigning as it's value an array with a named "text" element.

But this is irrelevant to `$philosophyList[]`. To understand how `$philosophyList[]` is working, you need to understand how foreach works; basically it takes each item in an array (in this case `$texte`) and assigns the value of that array item to a variable (in this case `$text`). This is just an easier way to do a for loop. They could just have easily done:

```
$philosophyList[] = $texte[$i]["text_text"];
```

Comment: Thank you Richard. It makes a lor more sense now.